# Trying to change text field color using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the text field change its color but it doesn't seem to work
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>   
  This is a title
  </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor()
    {
    alert("bla")
    document.getElemenyById("text1").style.background-color:red;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input id="text1" type="text" onkeypress="changeColor()">
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

- thank you

Comment: Use `backgroundColor` instead

Answer (score 4):

That's a syntax error. You can't use CSS syntax (`background-color: red`) inside JavaScript.

You want to actually assign a value (the string `"red"`) to a member of the `style` object called `backgroundColor`:

```
...style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("text1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jG95a/

There were four problems in your code:

- A typo in `getElementById()` (you had a "y" instead of a "t")
- `background-color` is not valid in JS dot notation, you need `backgroundColor`
- You need `=` not `:`
- `red` needs to be a string, `"red"`

Or to put those last three points another way, the way you had `background-color:red` is appropriate in a stylesheet, but not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If using Jquery use CSS() . If Plain Javascript

```
document.getElementById("text1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("text1").style("backgroundColor":"red");
```

One error is in "getElementById" typo

Comment: Did you test that second option?

Comment: yeah using jquery we write  $("#text1").style("backgroundColor":"red");

Comment: No we don't. What I was hinting at is that that is a syntax error. Try it and see. (For it to work with a colon you need to pass an object.)

Answer (score 2):

1) most of CSS attributes accessed from JavaScript need to replace all "-" and use rpn style, ie.

background-color becomes backgroundColor,

border-collapse becomes borderCollapse and so on.

2) When manipulating styles in JavaScript one may often need to update multiple attributes at once. A good and elegant method is to use the JavaScript "with" statement :

```
with(document.getElementById("text1").style) {
    backgroundColor = 'red' ;
    fontWeight = 'bold' ;
    // etc... 
}
```

3) the jQuery way is also simple :

```
$('#text1').css({
    "background-color": "red", 
    "font-weight": "bold"
}) ;
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/